# R studio source code build in QT Creator

Tags: r, makefile, qt-creator, rstudio

We have referred the steps provided in the following link to build the r studio source code

[click here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/wiki/RStudio-Development)

We have build the source code using QT Creator, while running the r studio project we got the 
Output like below screen shot. How to get the entire output

[image: R Studio output]

And also we have face some error while running the projects. Please find the error information below

**Project Name: consoleio**

```
Starting C:\rstudio-master\src\qtcreator-build\session\consoleio\consoleio.exe...
Error: Not enough arguments
Usage: consoleio.exe <program> [program-arguments]
C:\rstudio-master\src\qtcreator-build\session\consoleio\consoleio.exe exited with code 1
```

**Project Name :diagnostic**

```
Starting C:\rstudio-master\src\qtcreator-build\diagnostics\diagnostics.exe...
Log file: rdesktop.log
--------------------------------------------------
04 Aug 2014 08:29:43 [rdesktop] ERROR system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified); OCCURRED AT: virtual void core::http::NamedPipeAsyncClient::connectAndWriteRequest() C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\include/core/http/NamedPipeAsyncClient.hpp:83; LOGGED FROM: void desktop::NetworkReply::onError(const core::Error&) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\desktop\DesktopNetworkReply.cpp:279
07 Aug 2014 11:21:10 [rdesktop] ERROR system error 231 (All pipe instances are busy); OCCURRED AT: virtual void core::http::NamedPipeAsyncClient::connectAndWriteRequest() C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\include/core/http/NamedPipeAsyncClient.hpp:83; LOGGED FROM: void desktop::NetworkReply::onError(const core::Error&) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\desktop\DesktopNetworkReply.cpp:279
07 Aug 2014 11:21:11 [rdesktop] ERROR system error 231 (All pipe instances are busy); OCCURRED AT: virtual void core::http::NamedPipeAsyncClient::connectAndWriteRequest() C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\include/core/http/NamedPipeAsyncClient.hpp:83; LOGGED FROM: void desktop::NetworkReply::onError(const core::Error&) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\desktop\DesktopNetworkReply.cpp:279…………..
```

**ProjectName: rsession**

[image: R Session Exception]

**ProjectName :urlopener**

```
Starting C:\rstudio-master\src\qtcreator-build\desktop\urlopener\urlopener.exe...
SHIMVIEW: ShimInfo(Complete)
Error: Not enough arguments
C:\rstudio-master\src\qtcreator-build\desktop\urlopener\urlopener.exe exited with code 1
```

How to resolve this error and debug the r studio source in QT creator

[image]

Comment: If you followed the instructions and it didnt work then its something specific to your setup, which might be hard for anyone here to duplicate. Try the RStudio support forums: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us (maybe you did already)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to run against the 64 bit version of R. Here's how to switch to 32 bit:

1. Open a new command prompt in your qtcreator-build directory
2. Run desktop\rstudio.exe
3. Immediately after pressing Enter, hold down Ctrl (or just use Ctrl+Enter to run the command), and keep it held down while RStudio launches
4. When the "Choose R Version" dialog pops up, select a 32 bit version of R.

See [this page](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/wiki/Installing-RStudio-Dependencies) for more details (scroll to the bottom for Windows-specific build help).

Comment: Hi  Jonathan,  Thank you for your help. We have tried the steps as per your previous update. R version selector popup opened for me . But still R studio launched with Menu options only. And also we have face some error while run the following commands in command prompt                                                                 cmake ../cpp -G"MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/g++.exe  I have attached the error screen shot in my question.

Comment: Hi, We have cleared the error while running the CMake command mentioned in my previous comment. Still we did not get the exact output we got only  Menu options from R studio